# How to use .contains for Array of Object in swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, realm, swift4, contains

```
 func addData(){
   if lac_combinedFilterArray[1][0] == true{
        let Lac = realm.objects(LegalAidClinics.self)//.filter("service.lac_service_filter == true")
        for lac in Lac{
            let filteredServices = lac.service.filter("lac_service_filter == true")
            for service in filteredServices{
                let service_index = filteredServices.index(of: service)
                if lac.service.contains(filteredServices[service_index!]){
                    if !lac_combined_Array.contains(where: {$0.lac.legal_aid_clinic_id == lac.legal_aid_clinic_id}){
                        lac_combined_Array.append(lac)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    if lac_combinedFilterArray[1][1] == true{
        let chapters = realm.objects(IBPChapters.self)
        for chapter in chapters{
            let filteredServices = chapter.service.filter("lac_service_filter == true")
            for service in filteredServices{
                let service_index = filteredServices.index(of: service)
                if chapter.service.contains(filteredServices[service_index!]){
                    if !lac_combined_Array.contains(element: Object){
                        lac_combined_Array.append(chapter)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I will append 2 objects in** `lac_combined_array` **and I want to put a condition**

```
if lac_combined_array.contains(where: {$0.IBPChapters.ibp_chapter_id == chapter.ibp_chapter_id})
```

**and**

```
if lac_combined_array.contains(where: {$0.LegalAidClinics.legal_aid_clinics_id == lac.legal_aid_clinics_id})
```

**How to use**  `.contains` **in array of object in swift4**

Comment: Have you actually put your codes to test? I think they work XD

Comment: Or if you are asking how to combine the conditions... just put && between them as you would an 'if' check

Comment: i tried but unfortunately , error occured

Comment: my `lac_combined_array` is array of object ,, I think the cause of error is when I use `IBPChapters` or `LegalAidClinics` inside `where condition`

Comment: i will not combined them in `.contains condition` @Ben Ong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the element's type and then make comparisons correspondingly if the array contains objects of different types:

```
    if lac_combined_array.contains(where: { (obj) -> Bool in
        if let chapters = obj as? IBPChapters {
            return chapters.ibp_chapter_id == chapter.ibp_chapter_id
        }
        else if let legalAidClinics = obj as? LegalAidClinics {
            return legalAidClinics.legal_aid_clinics_id == lac.legal_aid_clinics_id
        }
        return false
    }) {
        //......
    }
```

Comment: no sir, not the same properties. @yun CHEN , I just want to append 2 objects/model in array and use each of their properties

Comment: Enn..., but you added different objects `LegalAidClinics` and `IBPChapters` into the same array. The array you declared must be <Any>, that's why you have problem with `{where` expression.

Comment: i tried Any but still got error , and I tried AnyObject and error gone

Comment: About your model, just make it inherited from ICommonProperties, and add common properties. Keep the others.

Comment: my other function get affected because of the changes @Yun CHEN :(

Comment: I make some changes in my Post , please have a look @yun CHEN

Comment: Yes, it will cause that. So, maybe it's better to abandon `.contains` method. Just filter them in `for` loop manually.

Comment: my search function gets affected and I dont want to make changes to it , is there another way?

Comment: I added a new way in answer.

Comment: i tried your first answer and its not working , I will try the second one

Comment: OK，I make the answer simple, delete the first one.